# Found files and set autotask to check it later with commands

Tags: bash

Given that I find all the markdown files and save it as `found.md`, then schedule an auto-task to open `found.md` with vscode

```
find / -regex ".*\.pdf$" 2>/dev/null 1>found.md |
#later is peudocodes
at "code found.md" now + 10 minutes #how make this code working
```

find the files and check it automatically in case of forgetting. 
How could I set a timer for the commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems. Both are described in `man at`:

> For  both  at  and batch, **commands are read from standard input** or the
>   file specified with the -f option and executed.  The working directory, the environment (**except for the variables** BASH_VERSINFO, **DISPLAY**, EUID, GROUPS, SHELLOPTS, TERM, UID, and _) and the umask are retained from the time of invocation.

`at` can only read commands from a pipe or file. Specifying the command as an argument does not work. Your `at` is inside a pipe, but that pipe is empty, since all output got redirected.

`at` is not made for opening graphical programs, but you have a chance to make it work by setting the `DISPLAY` variable.

```
find / -regex '.*\.pdf$' 2>/dev/null 1>found.md
echo 'export DISPLAY=:0; code found.md' | at now + 10min
```

If that doesn't work, you could use `sleep` instead of `at`:

```
sleep 600; code found.md
```

However, with `sleep` you would have to keep the terminal open. As a workaround, you can use `nohup`:

```
nohup bash -c '(sleep 600; code found.md) &'
```

By the way, you could replace `-regex '.*\.pdf$'` with `-name '*.pdf'` or even `-iname '*.pdf'`.

Comment: it's not working at the moment with at version of BSD 2003 on Macos, I am trying to install a gnu at.

Comment: I don't think `at` is the problem. Since you are on MacOS the display server is different from X11 and `DISPLAY` will probably not work. I have no mac and cannot test this, but maybe the `open` command could work. Try `open -a Code` or `open -a code` to see if that will open the app. Then try `echo open -a Code | at now` and see if that works. If it does, use `echo open -a Code found.md | at now + 10min`.

Comment: @Sawajiri There is also another way: You can use `sleep` instead of `at`. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to schedule commands with `at`, you have to send those to its standard input. In `bash` and some other shells you could do:

```
at now + 30 minutes <<< "code found.md"
```

However, in a plain `sh` shell, you'd need to *pipe* your command into `at`:

```
echo "code found.md" | at now + 30 minutes
```

If you are using your shell interactively, you could also simply start `at` and have it ask for your command:

```
at now + 30 minutes    # hit [ENTER] here to start `at` with a prompt
code found.md          # enter your command and submit it with [ENTER]
                       # hit Ctrl+D to exit the prompt
```

PS: In all examples, `code found.md` is the command you want to schedule.

Comment: if `code` is a program that needs a display, you need to export `DISPLAY` in your scheduled command, e.g. `at now + 30 minutes <<< "DISPLAY=:0 code found.md"`. Have you tried `man at`?

Comment: my version of at is BSD 2003 in Macos, does it matter?